# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded - DES Decryption

Tags: java, cryptography

I am trying to decrypt a message on server - the error what I got is

Encryption technique used - DES.

> --Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded

I am having a very difficult time trying to solve this problem, 
any help will be appreciated

```
class TCPClient {
public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
    byte[] sentence, textEncrypted;
    String modifiedSentence;
    String password;
    BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6789);
    DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    password = "Passcode";
    byte[] salt = new byte[64];
    Random rnd = new Random();
    rnd.nextBytes(salt);
    byte[] data = deriveKey(password, salt, 64);

    // BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new
    // InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    System.out.println("Enter the Data to be transmisted to server\n");
    sentence = inFromUser.readLine().getBytes();
    SecretKey desKey = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES").generateSecret(new DESKeySpec(data));
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, desKey);
    textEncrypted = cipher.doFinal(sentence);
    outToServer.writeBytes(new String(textEncrypted) + '\n');
    clientSocket.close();
}

public static byte[] deriveKey(String password, byte[] salt, int keyLen) {
    SecretKeyFactory kf = null;
    try {
        kf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    KeySpec specs = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 1024, keyLen);
    SecretKey key = null;
    try {
        key = kf.generateSecret(specs);
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return key.getEncoded();
}
}
```

Server side code

```
class TCPServer {
public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
    String password = null;
    String capitalizedSentence;
    ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);

    while (true) {
        Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
        BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        password = "Passcode";
        byte[] salt = new byte[64];
        Random rnd = new Random();
        rnd.nextBytes(salt);
        byte[] data = deriveKey(password, salt, 64);
        byte [] EncyptedText = inFromClient.readLine().getBytes();
        System.out.println("Received Encrypted message " + EncyptedText);
        SecretKey desKey = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES").generateSecret(new DESKeySpec(data));
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, desKey);
        // Decrypt the text
        System.out.println("Text Received " + EncyptedText);
        byte[] textDecrypted = cipher.doFinal(EncyptedText);
        System.out.println("Text Decryted : " + new String(textDecrypted));

    }
}

public static byte[] deriveKey(String password, byte[] salt, int keyLen) {
        SecretKeyFactory kf = null;
        try {
            kf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        KeySpec specs = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 1024, keyLen);
        SecretKey key = null;
        try {
            key = kf.generateSecret(specs);
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return key.getEncoded();
}
}
```

Comment: Just brainstorming here but your client side salt is different from the server side one. Won't that cause any problem?

Comment: I did tried using salt but I end up with same error :(

Answer (score 0):

You will lose data doing this:

```
outToServer.writeBytes(new String(textEncrypted) + '\n');
```

besides that, it's not necessary. Ciphertext is not really text for modern ciphers, it's binary. And as sockets provide binary `InputStream`s and `OutputStream`s there is simply no reason to convert the ciphertext to strings either. All that is required is to convert possible input strings to binary (using the same encoding on both the client and server, of course - UTF-8 is preferred nowadays).

Comment: In modified code I am writing bytes instead of sending string over TCP. The only problem what I am facing is deriving the secret key at server, Please suggest me the way how I can share the key between system.

Comment: Well, in this case you probably want to share a binary file containing the key. I mean, nothing in there is secure anyway so I presume this is just testing. SecretKey.getEncoded(), KeyFactory... But that's another issue. To be secure, use TLS and a PKI scheme.